# search in divs within a DataTable

Tags: search, filter, datatable, datatables

I'm currently on a project in which I included partialviews in every single row of a datatable.
it used to not be in a datatable at all, but I thought it could be a good idea for the use of the search function.
but of course, the partialview contains many text spans, even an external js called summernote, which includes lots of hidden text spans itself, and the search results are including every text within the global div. no need to say this isn't as accurate as I thought it would be.

I've seen that the search plugin could let us filter, for example, every div that has *some* class, but what I'm looking for is a functionnality that lets us filter on text contained in divs that have *some* class. this way I could ignore every other unrelevant text, hidden or not.
is it even remotely possible ?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the JS map command. YXou can map a function to each div which will return true or false. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map. And as Kennedy has said: "we do it not because its easy - we do it because its hard ! ";) Finally they fly to the moon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plain magic thing which let you filter a div containing a text combined with the question for a class which has to be also included. but you may write such a thing byself or use data attributes. Here is something which might be useful. [filter multiple data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143462/filter-multiple-data-attributes)

Comment: ok thanks.
I'll look into it, but it seems like it's a bit too complicated for the purpose.